# UISwitch crash when value change without any log

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

MainControllerView -> ProtectionViewController as childview -> BackupViewController (as subview) -> UISwitch (as subview)

Если поместить UISwitch на ProtectionViewController, он работает. Убрать таргет для свитча, кликается как невиновный.

P.S. Таргет присутствует :) Дебажил, до него даже переход не осуществляется.

```
CGRect switchRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 65,
                                   110,
                                   25,
                                   10);

    self.switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:switchRect];

    self.switchButton.on = NO;
    [self.switchButton addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(switchToggled)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:self.switchButton];
```

Comment: Селектор есть соотвествующий? 
- (void)switchToggled {} ??

Comment: да. объявил контроллер через проперти - заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `ViewController`'ов вообще нет `subview`, они есть у `controller.view`. А в остальном слишком сумбурно написано и данных не хватает, что там делает ваш свитч? Ведь крашится что-то внутри его таргета, так приведите этот таргет или понаставьте брейкпоинтов и сами найдите что после чего именно крашится. Пока похоже на "У меня есть машина, она не едет, почему?"

**Обновление**

Написали вы это уже после моего коммента, ну да не суть. В целом, если падает именно на вызове таргета значит нет такого селектора - либо не у того класса дергаете (очень на это похоже, если вы в точности то же используете на `ProtectionViewController`, то похоже оно там, а не на `BackupViewController`), либо не та сигнатура (скажем, `-(void) switchToggled:(id) sender` вместе `-(void) switchToggled`)

Comment: Я же написал, что до таргета даже не доходит. Если бы проблема была в таргет-методе (внутри), вопрос звучал бы по другому.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Скорее всего я случайно намутил что-то с контроллерами. Вместо обычного создания контроллера, я сделал его как проперти. Все заработало.